# Read multiple observations per variable per line

Tags: r

I have a dataset that I'm not quite sure how to handle in **R**. It is a list of years and then accident costs for those years. There can be zero accidents for one year, in which case the line ends after the year. Or, there can be multiple accidents, in which case the accidents are separated by a space on a single line.

For example:

```
Year    amount (en millions de USD)
1954    2934.57     388.37      3328.94
1955     
1956    78.27
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Skip the first line and use read.table with fill=TRUE?

Comment: ...and some reshaping in the mix @AnandaMahto, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read this using `read.table`, and specify `fill = TRUE` and `skip = 1`, it should put NA into any missing element of a row. For example:

```
dat = read.table('~/tmp/test.txt', skip = 1, fill = TRUE)
    V1      V2     V3      V4
1 1954 2934.57 388.37 3328.94
2 1955      NA     NA      NA
3 1956   78.27     NA      NA
```

where I pasted your example in the file `~/tmp/test.txt`. Next I would use `melt` from the `reshape2` package to change the organisation of the data:

```
library(reshape2)
dat_melt = melt(dat, id.vars = c('V1'))
    V1 variable   value
1 1954       V2 2934.57
2 1955       V2      NA
3 1956       V2   78.27
4 1954       V3  388.37
5 1955       V3      NA
6 1956       V3      NA
7 1954       V4 3328.94
8 1955       V4      NA
9 1956       V4      NA
```

and to get the accident cost per year:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dat_melt, .(V1), summarise, sum_cost = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE))
    V1 sum_cost
1 1954  6651.88
2 1955     0.00
3 1956    78.27
```